# Edits geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I am trying to reconcile and post the edits. Before doing that I want to manage the edits in such way that the edits are queued before reconcile and post. I am doing this using c#.

Comment: Have you looked at [Obtaining changes made in the current edit session](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000002000000) and [Finding differences between versions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Finding_differences_between_versions/00010000021t000000/)?